# Function which access an object picked from an array and returns it to have attributes modified

Tags: javascript, function, object, return, return-value

I got this repetitive block which goes through some arrays and picks the current player
I'd like to have some sort of a function to allow me to access the Player object and edit certain attributes.

So I want this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < Room_Array.length; i++) {
    if (Room_Array[i][0] === PlayerObject[socket.id].RoomName) {
        for (let j = 0; j < Room_Array[i][2].length; j++) {
            if (Room_Array[i][2][j].SocketID === PlayerObject[socket.id].SocketID) {
                Room_Array[i][2][j].IsSuspended = PlayerObject[socket.id].IsSuspended;
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

To be usable like this:
`PlayerPicked.IsSuspended = 0; // value is not important`
Without having to write the block multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer.
This is the function:

```
function Player_Return_BySocketID (P_Room_Array, P_RoomName, P_SocketID)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < P_Room_Array.length; i++)
    {
        if (P_Room_Array[i][0] === P_RoomName)
        {
            for (let j = 0; j < P_Room_Array[i][2].length; j++)
            {
                if (P_Room_Array[i][2][j].SocketID === P_SocketID)
                {
                    return P_Room_Array[i][2][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it is used like so:

```
PlayerPicked = Player_Return_BySocketID(Room_Array, PlayerObject[socket.id].RoomName, PlayerObject[socket.id].SocketID);
PlayerPicked.SuspendedStatus = PlayerObject[socket.id].SuspendedStatus;
```

The PlayerPicked therefore has access to all the attributes `P_Room_Array[i][2][j]` has.